# std::reference_wrapper v.s. int&

Tags: c++, c++11, reference-wrapper

I was trying out the `std::reference_wrapper` with the following snippet

```cpp
int a = 42, b = 52;
std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<int>> t = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a));

std::get<0>(t) = b;
std::cout << "t[0] = " << std::get<0>(t) << ", a = " << a << ", b = " << b
          << std::endl;
```

The output is `t[0] = 52, a = 42, b = 52`, which not surprising.

However, if I just use `auto` for `t`, namely

```cpp
int a = 42, b = 52;
auto t = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a));

std::get<0>(t) = b;
std::cout << "t[0] = " << std::get<0>(t) << ", a = " << a << ", b = " << b
          << std::endl;
```

Then I got `t[0] = 52, a = 52, b = 52`

Looks like the type becomes `int&`. Then I have some questions:

1. I thought `std::ref` gives us `std::reference_wrapper` rather than `&`?
2. How I should explain the case of `&` and why it is different from `std::reference_wrapper`.
3. I also noticed that, in the case of `std::reference_wrapper`, `std::get<0>(t) = 52;` does not compile. (While in the case of `&` it does). the error is "calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::reference_wrapper'". Could someone explain that in more detail?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I thought std::ref gives us std::reference_wrapper rather than &?

That's not a question, but you thought correctly.

> 2. How I should explain the case of & and why it is different from std::reference_wrapper.

When a `std::reference_wrapper` argument passed to `std::make_tuple`, the resulting tuple will have a reference member rather than a reference wrapper.

The difference in behaviour is because when you assign a reference, you modify the referred object while when you assign a reference wrapper, you instead rebind the wrapper to refer to another object and don't modify the referred object.

> I also noticed that, in the case of std::reference_wrapper, std::get<0>(t) = 52; does not compile. (While in the case of & it does). the error is "calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::reference_wrapper'". Could someone explain that in more detail?

`std::reference_wrapper` doesn't have an assignment operator for the referred type. It only has assignment operator for another reference wrapper. `std::reference_wrapper` has an implicitly converting constructor that accepts an lvalue, but not one that accepts an rvalue.

That is why you can assign `b` which is an lvalue, but cannot assign 52 which is a prvalue. This is a good thing because the lifetime of the temporary object cannot be extended by the reference wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @eerorika for explaining the difference! Then the remaining followup: is there a good reason why after the `std::make_tuple`, the reference wrapper become a simple reference (like you indicated in 2) by default.